# sending binary dns packet to server using curl

Tags: curl, dns, wireshark

I am trying to use Wireshark and curl to send a DNS packet to a DNS server for a DNS response. So, instead of using `curl -v --doh-url https://dns-server.example.com https://www.google.com`, I want to use something along the lines of `curl --data-binary @filename http://example.com/` to POST a binary dns packet to a dns server (i.e. `https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query`). Is there a curl command that will allow me to post to a server instead of a url?

Notes:

- `--doh-url` specifies which DNS-over-HTTPS (DOH) server to use to resolve hostnames, instead of using the default name resolver mechanism. The URL must be HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if you just have a tool that creates the DNS packet then `--data-binary` is all you need. And you probably want to make sure you set the right `Content-Type:` as well.

Alternatively, you use the [doh](https://github.com/curl/doh) tool we're working on for exactly this purpose, which uses libcurl to send a DNS query to the given DoH server.

Comment: Is there anyway to send a dns request to a DOH server that's running on your local machine? I have `nginx` set up  and for testing purposes I'm trying to use `curl --doh-url https://127.0.0.1 https://www.google.com` to get a dns response but I get hit with error `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve hostname`.